# nginx ssl auth: Loggin Requests

Tags: nginx

Does (or can) nginx log which certificates were used to log into a website?

I have configured nginx to perform ssl client authentication (with client pkcs12 files that I have signed with my own root certificate) the relevant portion of the config is:

```
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate server_certificate
        ssl_certificate_key server_private_key
        ssl_client_certificate client_root_signing_certificate
        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

I believe that it is working correctly, but for every signed certificate I issue, I would like the certificate to be recorded so I can see what certificate was used to log in when. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some SSL client cert variables to your log format (adjust to fit where and how your current logging it set up):

```
log_format combined_sslclient '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$ssl_client_s_dn($ssl_client_serial)"';
access_log log/access.log combined_sslclient
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Shane, do you know why some of the variables have to be in double quotes inside of single quotes (i.e. request and http_referer)?

Comment: They don't have to be at all - just makes for easier parsing for variables that can contain more complex strings.